# XTLS Xray - connection ends > proxy/vless/inbound: id is not able to use "". Note that the pure TLS proxy has certain TLS in TLS characters

Tags: vpn, openbsd

I am trying to setup a XTLS Xray server (Version 1.8.3) on an OpenBSD VPS. I am not using any CA issued certificate, instead one generated with `xray tls cert` to maintain server's anonymity.

The server configuration is the following:

```
{
"log": {
    "loglevel": "warning"
},
"dns": {
    "servers": [
        "<dns server address>"
    ]
},
"inbounds": [
    {
        "listen": "0.0.0.0",
        "port": 1234,
        "protocol": "vless",
        "settings": {
            "clients": [
                {
                    "id": "<client id>",
                    "level": 0,
                    "email": "abc@example.com",
                    "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                }
            ],
            "decryption": "none"
        },
        "streamSettings": {
            "network": "tcp",
            "security": "tls",
            "tlsSettings": {
                "serverName": "<server ip>",
                "alpn": [
                    "h2",
                    "http/1.1"
                ],
                "certificates": [
                    {
                      "certificate": [
                        <certificate>
                      ],
                      "key": [
                        <key>
                      ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
],
"outbounds": [
    {
        "protocol": "freedom",
        "tag": "direct"
    }
]
```

}

And the client config looks like the following:

```
{
"log": {
    "loglevel": "warning"
},
"inbounds": [
    {
        "listen": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": "1080",
        "protocol": "socks",
        "settings": {
            "auth": "noauth",
            "udp": true,
            "ip": "127.0.0.1"
        }
    }
],
"outbounds": [
    {
        "protocol": "vless",
        "settings": {
            "vnext": [
                {
                    "address": "<server ip address>,
                    "port": 1234,
                    "users": [
                        {
                            "id": "<client id>",
                            "encryption": "none",
                            "level": 0,
                            "flow": "xtls-rprx-vision"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "streamSettings": {
            "network": "tcp",
            "security": "tls",
            "tlsSettings": {
                "serverName": "<server ip address>",
                "allowInsecure": true,
                "fingerprint": "chrome"
            }
        },
        "tag": "proxy"
    }
],
"routing": {
    "domainStrategy": "AsIs"
}
```

}

And it shows the following error on the server side: `connection ends > proxy/vless/inbound:  id is not able to use "". Note that the pure TLS proxy has certain TLS in TLS characters.` and internet becomes inaccessible to the client.

So, where's the issue and how can I fix it?